# Query on ElasticSearch date fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document in elastic search with some date field. I need to query the index to pull documents having date prior to a specified date.
      {
        "_index": "*********",
        "_type": "**********",
        "_id": "-2116171797",
        "_source": {

```
      "GRP": "UP1",
      "CTDATE": "2019-04-26 00:00:00"

    }
```

i have tried using rangeQuery in below 2 ways:

1. QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("GRP", "UP1"))
                       .filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("CTDATE")
                               .lt(CTDATE1).format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
2. QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("GRP", "UP1"))
                       .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("CTDATE")
                               .lt(CTDATE1).format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

It returns all the date irrespective of the date

Comment: What is CTDATE1 here?

Comment: CTDATE1 is the input value which is Java util Date object

Comment: It might be a Java data format conversion problem. Did you try to give the date CTDATE1 explocitly as a string?

Comment: Giving CTDATE1 as string also did not work